# Using DSR MODEL provided by NS3 ，CAN‘T communication within diffrernt channels

Tags: c++, adhoc, ns-3

Put 3 groups nodes in three **adhoc** channels and those Nodes are in same **IPV4** net

here is the **problem** ：

```
assert failed. cond="mainVector.front () == source", file=../src/dsr/model/dsr-options.cc, line=908
terminate called without an active exception
```

I really want to know how you communicate between different channels？
please help me get out of this (╥﹏╥)  many thanks

```
#include "ns3/core-module.h"
#include "ns3/point-to-point-module.h"
#include "ns3/network-module.h"
#include "ns3/applications-module.h"
#include "ns3/wifi-module.h"
#include "ns3/mobility-module.h"
#include "ns3/csma-module.h"
#include "ns3/internet-module.h"
#include "ns3/netanim-module.h"
#include "ns3/olsr-module.h"
#include "ns3/dsr-module.h"
#include "ns3/dsdv-module.h"
using namespace ns3;
NS_LOG_COMPONENT_DEFINE ("ThirdScriptExample");
int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Time::SetResolution (Time::NS);
  bool verbose = true;
  uint32_t nWifi = 3; //设置 无线站点个数
  //bool tracing = false;
  CommandLine cmd;
  cmd.AddValue ("nWifi", "Number of wifi STA devices", nWifi);
  cmd.AddValue ("verbose", "Tell echo applications to log if true", verbose);
  //用命令行修改参数
  cmd.Parse (argc,argv);

  if (nWifi > 250)
    {
      std::cout << "Too many wifi or csma nodes, no more than 250 each." << std::endl;
      return 1;
    }
  if (verbose)
    {
      LogComponentEnable ("UdpEchoClientApplication", LOG_LEVEL_ALL);
      LogComponentEnable ("UdpEchoServerApplication", LOG_LEVEL_ALL);
    }

  NodeContainer wifiStaNodes;
  wifiStaNodes.Create (nWifi);  //创建无线站点STA的节点
  NodeContainer wifiApNode;
  wifiApNode.Create(1);   //创建一个AP节点
//**************************
  NodeContainer wifiStaNodes2;
  wifiStaNodes2.Create (5);  //创建无线站点STA的节点
  NodeContainer wifiApNode2;
  wifiApNode2.Create(1);   //创建一个AP节点
//****************************

  //*************************************************
  NodeContainer nodeall;
  nodeall.Add(wifiStaNodes);
  nodeall.Add(wifiStaNodes2);
  nodeall.Add(wifiApNode);
  nodeall.Add(wifiApNode2);
  //*************************************************

  YansWifiChannelHelper channel = YansWifiChannelHelper::Default ();   //使用默认的信道模型
  YansWifiPhyHelper phy = YansWifiPhyHelper::Default ();  //使用默认的PHY模型
  phy.SetChannel (channel.Create ());  //创建通道对象并把他关联到物理层对象管理器
  WifiHelper wifi;
  wifi.SetRemoteStationManager ("ns3::AarfWifiManager");  //设置wifi助手用AARF速率控制算法
 //*******************************************************
    YansWifiChannelHelper channel1 = YansWifiChannelHelper::Default ();   //使用默认的信道模型
     YansWifiPhyHelper phy1 = YansWifiPhyHelper::Default ();  //使用默认的PHY模型
     phy1.SetChannel (channel1.Create ());  //创建通道对象并把他关联到物理层对象管理器
     wifi.SetStandard (WIFI_PHY_STANDARD_80211b);
     NqosWifiMacHelper wifiMac = NqosWifiMacHelper::Default ();
     wifiMac.SetType ("ns3::AdhocWifiMac");
     NodeContainer mixnode1;
     mixnode1.Add(wifiStaNodes);
     mixnode1.Add(wifiApNode);
     NetDeviceContainer devices = wifi.Install (phy1, wifiMac, mixnode1);
 //*******************************************************
     YansWifiChannelHelper channel3 = YansWifiChannelHelper::Default ();   //使用默认的信道模型
      YansWifiPhyHelper phy3 = YansWifiPhyHelper::Default ();  //使用默认的PHY模型
      phy3.SetChannel (channel3.Create ());  //创建通道对象并把他关联到物理层对象管理器
      NodeContainer wifiDAP;
      wifiDAP.Add(wifiApNode2);
      wifiDAP.Add(wifiApNode);
      wifi.SetStandard (WIFI_PHY_STANDARD_80211b);
      NqosWifiMacHelper wifiMac3 = NqosWifiMacHelper::Default ();
      wifiMac3.SetType ("ns3::AdhocWifiMac");
      NetDeviceContainer devices3 = wifi.Install (phy3, wifiMac3, wifiDAP);
 //*******************************************************
      YansWifiChannelHelper channel4 = YansWifiChannelHelper::Default ();   //使用默认的信道模型
       YansWifiPhyHelper phy4 = YansWifiPhyHelper::Default ();  //使用默认的PHY模型
       phy4.SetChannel (channel4.Create ());  //创建通道对象并把他关联到物理层对象管理器
       wifi.SetStandard (WIFI_PHY_STANDARD_80211b);
       NqosWifiMacHelper wifiMac4 = NqosWifiMacHelper::Default ();
       wifiMac4.SetType ("ns3::AdhocWifiMac");
       NodeContainer mixnode2;
       mixnode2.Add(wifiStaNodes2);
       mixnode2.Add(wifiApNode2);
       NetDeviceContainer devices4 = wifi.Install (phy4, wifiMac4, mixnode2);
//******************************************************

  // 加入移动模型，让STA可以移动，AP固定
  MobilityHelper mobility;
  mobility.SetPositionAllocator ("ns3::GridPositionAllocator",
                                 "MinX", DoubleValue (0.0),
                                 "MinY", DoubleValue (0.0),
                                 "DeltaX", DoubleValue (5.0),
                                 "DeltaY", DoubleValue (10.0),
                                 "GridWidth", UintegerValue (3),
                                 "LayoutType", StringValue ("RowFirst"));
  //设置初始时，节点的摆放位置
  mobility.SetMobilityModel ("ns3::RandomWalk2dMobilityModel",   //设置移动模式为"ns3::RandomWalk2dMobilityModel"，随机移动
                             "Bounds", RectangleValue (Rectangle (-50, 50, -50, 50)));   //移动范围
  mobility.Install (wifiStaNodes);
  //**********************************************
  mobility.Install (wifiStaNodes2);
  //**********************************************
  mobility.SetMobilityModel ("ns3::ConstantPositionMobilityModel");  //设置AP的不能够移动的，"ns3::ConstantPositionMobilityModel"
  mobility.Install (wifiApNode);
  //**********************************************
  mobility.Install (wifiApNode2);
  //**********************************************
  //mobility.Install(nodeall);

  InternetStackHelper internet;
  DsrMainHelper dsrMain;
  DsrHelper dsr;
  internet.Install (nodeall);
  dsrMain.Install (dsr, nodeall);
/*
  InternetStackHelper stack;
  ns3::OlsrHelper Olsr;
  stack.SetRoutingHelper(Olsr);
  stack.Install(nodeall);
*/
   //********************************************************
  Ipv4AddressHelper address;
  address.SetBase ("198.1.2.0", "255.255.255.0");
  Ipv4InterfaceContainer wifiInterfaces3;
  wifiInterfaces3=address.Assign (devices3);
//*******************************************************
  address.SetBase ("198.1.0.0", "255.255.255.0");
  Ipv4InterfaceContainer mixInterfaces;
    mixInterfaces=address.Assign (devices);
 //********************************************************
    address.SetBase ("198.2.0.0", "255.255.255.0");
    Ipv4InterfaceContainer mixInterfaces4;
      mixInterfaces4=address.Assign (devices4);

      std::cout<<"mi "<<mixInterfaces4.GetAddress(5)<<std::endl;
 //********************************************************
  //安装UDP程序，使用UDP，与之前的UDP的使用方法一致
  UdpEchoServerHelper echoServer (9);
  ApplicationContainer serverApps = echoServer.Install (wifiStaNodes2.Get (0));//wifiApNode2
  serverApps.Start (Seconds (1.0));
  serverApps.Stop (Seconds (40.0));
  UdpEchoClientHelper echoClient (mixInterfaces4.GetAddress (0), 9);
  echoClient.SetAttribute ("MaxPackets", UintegerValue (10000));
  echoClient.SetAttribute ("Interval", TimeValue (Seconds(1 / ((double) 20))));
  echoClient.SetAttribute ("PacketSize", UintegerValue (1024));
  ApplicationContainer clientApps =
    echoClient.Install (wifiStaNodes2.Get (1));
  clientApps.Start (Seconds (2.0));
  clientApps.Stop (Seconds (40.0));

  //Ipv4GlobalRoutingHelper::PopulateRoutingTables ();
  phy4.EnablePcap("AAA",wifiStaNodes2);
  Simulator::Stop (Seconds (41.0));
  AnimationInterface anim("amix.xml");
  Simulator::Run ();
  Simulator::Destroy ();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question has been on hold for a long time, no one is willing to help me, it may be because my problem is too simple.

This problem can be known by interpreting the DSR source file code. The DSR module provided by NS3 cannot provide cross-gateway functions at all, and DSR does not support multiple interfaces of one node during the implementation process. If you do this, it is likely because of you setting the order of the interfaces, which causes the program to report an error.

**The solution:**

1. First, I recorded the interface of each node in the dsr_routing
   file, and then each interface handles the forwarding of `rreq`, so
   that the `rreq` message is forwarded out of the gateway.
2. When the destination node receives the `rreq` message, it will
   reply. Rrep message, also need to note that the address in the
   nodelist is a routing path address, but only represents an interface
   of a node, so you also need to define a global map.

   This map will record which is the node corresponding to the interface,

The specific idea is mentioned above, of course, many details are not mentioned. If you want to explore the details, you can contact me.